# Probabilistic line of best fit

Tags: probability

I have data about pedestrian counts from multiple sensors along a street. I know the location of each sensor. Assume that the street has total length L.

I want a function F(l,t) that gives pedestrian counts given a length l (along the street)and a time t. The graph below shows pedestrian counts from various sensors within 0 to L, i want to map the distribution to the function described. I have data about pedestrian counts over a 24hr for multiple days/hourly data. What is the best way to get the line of best fit that gives F?

[image]